# What am I missing to make ScrollSpy work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollspy

I've copied the files from http://jsfiddle.net/ia_archiver/9AgUS/ as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>MWE Scrollspy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/scrollspy.css" />
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
    <div id="post1" class="box">
        <h1>Post 1</h1>
        <p> Scroll Down?</p>
    </div>
    <div id="post2" class="box"><h1>Post 2</h1></div>
    <div id="post3" class="box"><h1>Post 3</h1></div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#post1">Post 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#post2">Post 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#post3">Post 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in scrollspy.html, and:

```
@import url(http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css);
html{ background: #fff;}
.box{
    margin: 20px; padding: 15px;
    background: #eee;
    height: 500px;
}
#navbar{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.nav li a{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.nav li a:hover{
    color: #f33 !important;
    background: none;
}
.nav li.active a{
    color: #f55;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

in scrollspy.css.

I don't see what I'm missing, though the ScrollSpy feature does not work (while all CSS is all right).

Can you help me identify what I'm clearly missing??  Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE 2015-04-02:** Here is what I get on the console:

```
HTML1406: Invalid tag start: "<?". Question marks should not start tags. 
scrollspy.html, line 1 character 2
HTML1524: Invalid DOCTYPE. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>". 
scrollspy.html, line 2 character 1
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
bootstrap-scrollspy.js, line 1 character 1
```

Not that explicit -- at least to me.

Comment: Do you have anything in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to reference the bootstrap javascript file (at least from CDN). Your script reference is to the old github hosted file, which is now a redirect to the bootstrap homepage instead of the js file for the scrollspy.

Official CDN:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9AgUS/1736/

Comment: May I just ignore the first 2 warnings from the console?